# React Material-UI breakpoint does not work

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Im trying to make a responsive navbar with Material-UI. And I am trying to **hide** `IconButton` between from 960px to 1920px and up.  
 And **show** the `IconButton` from 0px to 960px. 
But it works below `960px` 

Here is part of my code of `IconButton` and `ul` ;

```
    <div className={classes.right}>
        <IconButton
          edge='end'
          className={classes.btnMenu}
          size='medium'
          onClick={(e) => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}
        >
          <MenuIcon
            className={classes.btnMenuMenu}
            size='medium'
          ></MenuIcon>
        </IconButton>
        <ul
          className={`${classes.list} ${
            showMenu ? classes.showList : classes.removeList
          } `}
        >
          <li className={classes.li}>
            <a href='#!' className={classes.navLink}>
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={classes.li}>
            <a href='#!' className={classes.navLink}>
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={classes.li}>
            <a href='#!' className={classes.navLink}>
              Portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={classes.li}>
            <a href='#!' className={classes.navLink}>
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

In `styles.js` file, I applied the following code to `IconButton`;

```
btnMenu: {
width: '100%',
display: 'none',
[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
  display: 'inline-block',
 },
},
```

But it still shows the `IconButton` above `ul`, just like in the picture below; 
And here is my github repo; [GitHub-Repo](https://github.com/sbayrak/materialui-navbar) 
 
[image]

Comment: Right now you ask MUI to apply the style if it’s lower than 600px you should put ‘theme.breakpoint.up(md)’ and apply the style for hide it to this. Then for show it on the lower display just add a theme.breakpoint.down(md) and apply the style too that would work. You can check the breakpoint/css media queries logic here https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/ the other problem you got is your css rules they never gonna hide your button with this you should put display: none instead

Comment: I edited the `.btnMenu` to `display : 'flex' ` and add `[theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    }, ` but it still does not work... I applied the same thing to Typography in `.left` div, it works well but i couldnt make IconButton to work...

Comment: I create a pull request with the fix on your repo GitHub when I’m home you would just have to review and merge if it’s ok for you

Comment: Alright, then I am not pushing newer changes. I am waiting for your response! thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is; 
I changed `MenuIcon` to a fontawesome's `bars` icon and applied the `.btnMenu` class to the `<i>...</i>` tag, and it works well now... Im still not %100 sure what caused `IconButton` to not work but changing it to what I said above, it works...

```
<div className={classes.right}>
         
        <Button onClick={(e) => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}>
          <i className={` ${classes.btnMenu} fas fa-bars`}></i>
        </Button>
        <ul
          className={`${classes.list} ${classes.list2} ${
            showMenu ? classes.showList : classes.removeList
          } `}
        >
          <li className={classes.li}>
            <a href='#!' className={classes.navLink}>
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={classes.li}>
            <a href='#!' className={classes.navLink}>
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={classes.li}>
            <a href='#!' className={classes.navLink}>
              Portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={classes.li}>
            <a href='#!' className={classes.navLink}>
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```